# Can I find out the method in a base class overridden by a method in a derived class, directly in C# and Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In a class, for a method declared with `override`, how can I find the method from a base class of the class which is overridden by the method?

In Visual Studio 2015, the `reference` shown in the line before the declaration of the overriding method, includes

- the definition and usage of the method being overridden in the base class
- the definition of a method from a sibling class derived from the base class
- maybe more...

Why is a method from a sibling class overriding the same method in the base class considered a reference to the method of the class?

Is a overriding method from a class derived from the class considered a reference to the method of the class?

Can I find out the method being overridden in the base class directly, instead of manually filtering the results from `reference`?

Comment: use go to definition on the base class from the derived class definition

Comment: As yourself this...what is the nature of the relationship?  Is it one to one, one to many, many to one, etc.  How would YOU devise an algorithm to to ensure that you are always going to the overridden method directly when there could be more than one instance?

Comment: @Tim sorry, to try to clarify my point, you could have any number of overriding implementations.  How do you guarantee there is only one and find that method directly without filtering?

Comment: @David I am looking for the overridden method in a base class from a method in a derived class, not an overriding method in a derived class from a method in a base class. In the former case, is it possible that there might be multiple methods from possibly different base classes overridden by a method in a derived class?  In the latter case, I am satisfied with all the methods that overrides the method in the base class.

Comment: @Tim ahh, I apologize, the wording of your question confused me.  In that case simply use Ehsan's suggestion and go to definition.  You can also use tools like resharper which will allow you to go directly from the overridden method to the base method with a little icon to the left of the method signature.